# install win8.1 from usb

Tags: boot, usb, windows-8.1

I have an Win8.1 installation on usb. 
When I want to boot installation from this, I get an error:

The boot configuration data file doesn't contain valid information for an operating system.

The disk is already formatted. 
I have only this usb stick, none recovery dvds. 
How can I fix this? Maybe fixmbr would help? 
But don't know how to do it in this situation. Maybe from some linux distro booted from usb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the pendrive problem.
After created it once more time problem disappeared.